# Symfony2 Entity with date, calculate average per day

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have an entity Amount

with

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="float")
 */
private $value;

/**
 * @Exclude
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;
```

and some more fields

I want to calculate the average Value per day

right now i create for everyday a DateTime

```
    $date=new \DateTime();
    $yesterday = new \ DateTime();
    $yesterday->modify("- 1 day");
    $beforeYesterday = new \ DateTime();
    $beforeYesterday->modify("- 2 days");    
    ...
```

and i loop through all amounts

```
    $averageCounts=[];

    foreach ($amounts as $amount) {
        if($amount->getCreatedAt()->format("d.m.Y") == $date->format("d.m.Y") ){
            $averageCounts['today'] += $amount->getValue();                
        }

        if($amount->getCreatedAt()->format("d.m.Y") == $yesterday->format("d.m.Y") ){ 
           $averageCounts['yesterday'] += $amount->getValue(); 
        }

    }

    $averagePerDay = ($averageCounts['today'] + $averageCounts['yesterday']) / count($averageCount) ;
```

so its obviuous i cant go on like this, can anybody point me to an elegant way of calculating the average value per day ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `group by` so you will have the next sql:

`SELECT AVG(t.value), t.create_at FROM table AS t GROUP BY(t.create_at)`

In your repository you can translate in `dql`:

```
$q = $em->createQuery();
$dql = "select AVG(t.value), DAY(t.createdAt)
        cdate  from MyProject\Model\Table t WHERE t.type=:param GROUP BY cdate";

$q->setDql($dql)->setParameter('param', $param);
```

Comment: `WHERE  t.type=:param` and after `$q->setDQL($dql)->setParameter('param', $param)`

Comment: hm sorry it does not seem to work, i think `GROUP BY t.createdAt` needs to be formatted as `d.m.Y` , now it returns an array with 18 entries (count of all amounts) instead of foreach day an array ( 3 days )

Comment: i think i have to use the inbuilt DAY() functiion but when i do `GROUP BY DAY(t.createdAt)` it throws error ` line 0, col 78 near 'DAY(t.createdAt)': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable.`

Comment: Made some modifications could you try this one

Comment: thank you very much looks pretty good, but results in `Error: Expected known function, got 'DATE_FORMAT'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70793/discussion-between-alexandru-olaru-and-john-smith).